# How to change encoding in apache fop configuration? (Default is Identity-H)

Tags: java, apache, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have some problem with apache fop. As  i use apache fop for generating pdf file (using xsl-fo). But i can't extract generated pdf file content or when i copy text from pdf and paste to word file it appears like below: 
[pdf file content in word document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htTEH.png)

Fop configuration file is below:

```
 <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <filterList>
        <value>flate</value>
      </filterList>
<entry>
    <key>fontBaseDir</key>
<value>
D:\TestProject\apache-tomcat-5.5.23\webapps\reporter\shared\fonts
</value>
  </entry>
      <fonts>
 <!-- Arial Font-->
 <font metrics-file="arial.xml" kerning="yes" embed-file="arial.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
 </font>
 <font metrics-file="arialbd.xml" kerning="yes" embed-file="arialbd.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
 </font>
 <font metrics-file="ariali.xml" kerning="yes" embed-file="ariali.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
 </font>
 <font metrics-file="arialbi.xml" kerning="yes" embed-file="arialbi.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
 </font>
</fonts>
    </renderer>
```

I want to notice that i use Azeri (Turkish) symbols in pdf file.

Comment: Which version of FOP are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing FOP version to 2.1 my problem resolved.